# Placing an image in the bottom of an UITextfield as background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uitextfield

After a lot of search I am posting this Question, I have to place an image at the bottom of a UITextfield, I have tried it with the following code :

```
letterField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
letterField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
letterField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
letterField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];
[letterField  setLeftView:myView];
[letterField  setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[myView release];
// letterField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"];  
// [letterField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];  
letterField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
letterField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[yourtextfield insertSubview:imgViewTitleBackGround atIndex:0];// mgViewTitleBackGround is image view with background image.
```

//Or

```
[yourtextfield setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];// you can add your image
yourtextfield.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope, this will help you..enjoy

Comment: Hey @Nit  Thank u so much for the answer, I tried with that No luck.

Comment: Hey @Nit the later one worked a bit closer, but the problem is the image is being placed at the center of the textfield.
the former is stretching the image to whole of the textfield

Comment: where you want image in textfield just define clearly so i can understand and help you..

Comment: I want the image at the bottom of the textfield. it should like the "_".

Comment: Just resize your image and see it's work fine...image should size of textfield

Comment: Hey Nit Finally I got the output by adjusting the image as said by u, I mixed the code given by u and @graver finally figured it out like this :
 UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];
myView.center = CGPointMake(5, 27);
 [letterField insertSubview:myView atIndex:0];
[myView release];

Comment: Everything is working fine but i am having a small issue here when i am entering the data in the textfield than after coming back to the page once again than the data in the textfield is remaining rather it shouldn't be there it should be a blank textfield. can u say me why it is happening so and i cross checked it, its happening bcoz of the code for the background image .

Comment: I have some textfields where i am entering the data, after sometime i am coming to the page again than that data in the textfield will not be present, now that i have to set a background image for that textfield and that we have done it, after adding the piece of code for background image, the data in the textfield  remains and doesn't give me blank textfields.......

Comment: No, that should be because of something else. Background image and text don't have any relationship. Than after use `yourtextfield.text = nil;` when want to cleat the textfield.

Comment: Okay..I have done something like myTextfield.text = @""; does it make any difference?

Comment: In your case not but when you are comparing string(textfield text) at that time that will make difference. added +1 in your last comment for good comment..

Comment: Okay Thank You...and I am comparing string and textfield.text in my case.

Comment: Hey @Nit could u say me how does they make the difference.

Comment: `if(yourtextfield == nil)
         {
              NSLog(@"1");   
         }
         else if (yourtextfield.text == @"")
         {
              NSLog(@"2");   
         }
         else if([yourtextfield.text isEqualToString:@""])
         {
              NSLog(@"3");   
         }
         else if ([yourtextfield.text isEqualToString:nil])
         {
              NSLog(@4");   
         }`  use this code block and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous answer was totally wrong. From what I can see your image is text_line.png - i suppose it's some kind of separator line, what can i suggest you to try is create a new UIView with the bounds of the UITextField, then add the text field inside this view and add the UIImage view again as subview of this view centering it properly. I don't know if this will fit your needs, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Hey @graver Thank u for the time , I have tried with this piece of code, When i am trying with it, its getting crashed saying SIGBART error.

Comment: Okay i will try with the way u said.

Comment: Hey garver Finally I got the output by adjusting the image as said by u, I mixed the code given by u and @Nit finally figured it out like this : UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]]; myView.center = CGPointMake(5, 27); [letterField insertSubview:myView atIndex:0]; [myView release];